# Momentum operator dot a vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, differentiation

Why is $P \cdot A = A \cdot P -i\hbar\nabla \cdot A$? I was just replacing $P=-i\hbar\nabla $  so I didn't get the first term on the right side

Comment: Did you hear about the Leibniz rule of differentiation?

Comment: I suppose, but I still don't get it... $P \cdot A = (-i\hbar\nabla) \cdot A =-i\hbar \nabla \cdot A$... where does the term $A \cdot P$ come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $P= -i\hbar\nabla$ is an operator that 'acts' on functions, the expression $P\cdot A$ is interpreted as the operator that first multiplies the function by the vector (field) A and then acts by dotting with P on the result. To differentiate a product you simply use the Leibniz rule. It becomes clear if you put in a function: 
$$ (P\cdot A) f = -i\hbar\nabla\cdot(Af) = -i\hbar f (\nabla\cdot A) -i\hbar A\cdot (\nabla f) = (A\cdot P - i\hbar\nabla\cdot A) f$$
The confusion stems from the fact that you are interpreting the $P\cdot A$ as simply a product instead of an operator(!) that first multiplies by A and then differentiates by dotting the result with $-i\hbar\nabla$. If $A$ is a constant vector then we simply get $P\cdot A = A\cdot P$, since the second term becomes zero.